# How to get logged in username to print in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print the value of currently logged in username in my main.html file. My login.html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Form Validation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    <script defer src="login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="main-holder">
        <h1 id="login-header">Login</h1>
        
        <div id="login-error-msg-holder">
          <p id="login-error-msg">Invalid username <span id="error-msg-second-line">and/or password</span></p>
        </div>
        
        <form id="login-form">
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Username">
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-form-submit">
        </form>
      </main> 
    
</body>
</html>
```

And the .js file looks like this:

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("login-error-msg");


loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = loginForm.username.value;
    const password = loginForm.password.value;

    if (username === "Erkki_Esimerkki" && password === "projekti") {
        window.location.href = "main.html";
       /* location.reload();*/
    } else {
        loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
    }
})
```

The username should be printed in a `p` element in my main.html which the user is directed after logging in through the login.html.

I tried creating a function in my login.html like so:

```
function getUsername() {
    let username = document.getElementById("username-field").value
    document.getElementById("userinfo").innerHTML += username
}
```

And calling the function in my main.js.

Comment: i guess u know that anyone that presses F12 can know the user and the password, right? i say it cuz this line: `if (username === "Erkki_Esimerkki" && password === "projekti")`

Comment: In what way does the code not work as expected?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  When you use the script debugger to step through the code, what specifically happens?

Comment: @ericmp Yes I know that, but im not focused on that yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` to store the username and then retrieve it in the `main.html` file.

You can use the `setItem` method to store the username in the `localStorage` and the `getItem` method to retrieve it.

```js
// login.js
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("login-error-msg");

loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const username = loginForm.username.value;
  const password = loginForm.password.value;

  if (username === "Erkki_Esimerkki" && password === "projekti") {
    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    window.location.href = "main.html";
  } else {
    loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
  }
});

// main.js

const username = localStorage.getItem("username");
document.getElementById("userinfo").innerHTML += username;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to somehow maintain the values. Since you did not specify a server-side technology, I will answer you using Javascript:

```
loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = loginForm.username.value;
    const password = loginForm.password.value;

    if (username === "Erkki_Esimerkki" && password === "projekti") {
        localStorage.setItem("username", username);
        window.location.href = "main.html";
       /* location.reload();*/
    } else {
        loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
    }
})
```

And on the other page:

```
document.write(`<p>${localStorage.get("username")}</p>`);
```